# JavaScript disconnect after jQuery replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In the application that I'm currently creating, I am doing several AJAX calls to the server and replacing parts of my page with partial views.  Everything seems to be working right except for my buttons which are "replaced" using the jQuery `replaceWith()` function.

In my actual code, I'm replacing a whole `<div>` not just a button, but the code [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/895/) will help illustrated my issue.

When the button is clicked, the JavaScript is called and thusly, that button is then updated.  However, try to click on that button again, the same JavaScript will NOT be called or executed.  There is some disconnect here that I'm missing.  (In my mind, every time that the button with a class of "updateButton" is clicked, the javascript should be executed.)  Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click','.updateButton',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    var now = new Date().getTime();

   var newButton = "<span class='btn btn-info updateButton'>Update Button " + now + "</span>"

    $(this).replaceWith(newButton);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/896/

Instead of binding the event to the button which will be removed (thus losing the event binding), bind it to an element that doesn't get removed but is an ancestor of that button.

Comment: Also, just a small note, you can replace `new Date().getTime()` with `$.now()`

Comment: @KevinB: Or `Date.now()`, oh wait, that's shorter. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the event handler on the document (as in Kevin B's answer), just re-bind it to the new button you've created to replace the old button with. This is a more efficient method of event handling because the event doesn't need to bubble all the way up the DOM tree to the document before the event fires.

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/900/

```
var replaceBtn = function(domBtn,e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var now = new Date().getTime();

   var newButton = $("<span class='btn btn-info updateButton'>Update Button " + now + "</span>");
    newButton.on('click',function(event) {
        replaceBtn(this,event);
    });

    $(domBtn).replaceWith(newButton);

}

$('.updateButton').click(function(event) {
     replaceBtn(this,event)
});
```